# Mostrar Ocultar Botão JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tendo dificuldades em implementar a função de mostrar e ocultar uma `div` em HTML com JavaScript.

O que preciso é que quando um retorno de me `servlet` estiver vazio ou `null`, oculte uma determinada `div`.
O mesmo deve acontecer ao contrário, por exemplo, quando o retorno do `servlet` não for vazio ou diferente de `null`, a `div` aparece.

Segue parte de meu código:

- Esta é a `div` que quero ocultar ou mostrar e o método `JavaScript`

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
                                    var a = '<%=a.getSoldes()%>';
                                    if (a !== null && a !== undefined) {
                                        document.getElementById('descricaosolucao').style.display = "block";
                                    } else {
                                        document.getElementById('descricaosolucao').style.display = "none";
                                    }
                                </script>
```

```html
<div id="descricaosolucao" class="descricaosolucao" style="display: none;">
                                        <p class="titulo-comp">Solução<%=dataSol%></p>
                                        <p ><%=a.getSoldes()%></p>
                                    </div>
```

Tenho pouco conhecimento em JavaScript e por isto gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Esse código `<%=a.getSoldes()%>` é que linguagem? isso é feito no servidor?

Comment: acho que é asp não é ?

Comment: O que vem no console.log(a)?

Comment: Pela sintaxe parece-me jsp, server side

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo em Java WEB JSP e no código `<%=a.getSoldes()%>` deve vir um texto.  Quando este vier vazio, a div deve ocultar.

Comment: Porque não fazer esse `if` diretamente em JSP já que não é algo que possa mais mudar depois de a página ser carregada ? Pode fazer o `if` e aplicar uma classe *css* com `display:none` diretamente no atributo `class`

Comment: Olá Isac.  Sou leigo ainda.  Por favor, poderias me mostrar como é na prática?  Como faço o div receber o parametro do JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se é uma coisa que não se altera após a página estar carregada o melhor é fazer do lado do servidor logo, colocando diretamente o estilo certo no `<div>`.

```
<div id="descricaosolucao" class="descricaosolucao" style="${dataSol?'':'display: none;'}">
     <p class="titulo-comp">Solução<%=dataSol%></p>
     <p ><%=a.getSoldes()%></p>
</div>
```

Em que usei um operador ternário diretamente no `style`:

```
style="${dataSol?'':'display: none;'}"
```

Se `dataSol` for diferente de `null` fica '' caso contrario fica `display:none;` e por isso esconde

Comment: Muito obrigado Isac.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja nas condições do if que você esta fazendo.
Digamos que "a.getSoldes()" esteja vazio, então a variável a ficaria assim:

```
var a = '';
```

Ambas comparações 'a !== null' e 'a !== undefined' retornam true.
Se você mudar a condição do if para 'a.length > 0' terá o comportamento que deseja.